# Is it not possible to have a covariant interface contain a generic type who's type parameter is the covariant type?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I have a covariant interface and generic class that is unrelated. I'd like the covariant interface to have a property that is an instance of that generic class on the covariant type, like so.

```
public interface IFoo<out T>
{
    Bar<T> barobj { get; set; }
}

public class Bar<T>
{
}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting an error

> Error CS1961  Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on 'IFoo<T>.barobj'. 'T' is covariant.

Does this mean that it's impossible to have a covariant interface with a generic type that uses the covariant type as the parameter? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I think it should also be `Bar<out T>`

Comment: @Amy generic parameters on classes can't be variant - only on interfaces

Comment: "generic class is unrelated" what does you mean by this?

Comment: @DStanley Oh, right, yeah.

Comment: @DStanley I missed the "that" part. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

An interface can only be covariant if it only allows *outputs* of the generic type.  Your interface is not covariant because *you can set the value* of `barobj`. If you make the property read-only, *then* it can be covariant if `barobj` is covariant. So that means you need a covariant interface for `Bar`:

```
public interface IFoo<out T>
{
    IBar<T> barobj { get; }
}

public class Bar<T> : IBar<T>
{
}

public interface IBar<out T> 
{
}
```